# Material UI <Grid> does not hide when using display

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use Material UI [`Grid`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/grid/) and I wanted to hide one item `Grid` if the screen is small, so I found something called [Display](https://mui.com/system/display/). My code looks like this:

```
function CRUDView() {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={1}
      direction="row"
      justify="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
        <span>XX</span>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6} display={{ xs: "none", lg: "block" }} >
        <span>YY</span>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

I don´t uderstand why it doesn't work (the text `YY` still appears) . Can't I use display with `Grid` maybe? If yes then why?

Comment: Try this for mobile only - `<Grid item component={Box} xs={12} sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' } }}> </Grid>`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [style functions](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/) are not automatically supported by the `Grid` component.

The easiest way to leverage the style functions is to use the [Box component](https://material-ui.com/components/box/). The `Box` component makes all of the style functions (such as [display](https://material-ui.com/system/display/)) available. The `Box` component has a [component prop](https://material-ui.com/components/box/#api) (which defaults to `div`) to support using `Box` to add style functions to another component.

The `Grid` component similarly has a [component prop](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#props), so you can either have a `Grid` that delegates its rendering to a `Box` or a `Box` that delegates to a `Grid`.

The example below (based on your code) shows both ways of using `Box` and `Grid` together.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  gridItem: {
    border: "1px solid red"
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={1}
      direction="row"
      justify="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Grid className={classes.gridItem} item xs={12} lg={6}>
        <span>XX</span>
      </Grid>
      <Box
        component={Grid}
        className={classes.gridItem}
        item
        xs={3}
        display={{ xs: "none", lg: "block" }}
      >
        <span>YY</span>
      </Box>
      <Grid
        component={Box}
        className={classes.gridItem}
        item
        xs={3}
        display={{ xs: "none", lg: "block" }}
      >
        <span>ZZ</span>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Use system style functions with Grid]

Answer (score 16):

**For MUI v5:**

In MUI v5 the `<Hidden>` tag got deprecated in favor for `sx.display` property withing `<Grid>` and `<Box>` tags - [display documentation](https://mui.com/system/display/).

**For MUI v4 and earlier:**

MUI exposes a `<Hidden>` component to achieve this. Just wrap component you want to hide for specific screen size:

```
      <Hidden xsDown >
          <p>Hide me on XS view port width.</p>
      </Hidden>
```

You can find more examples in the [hidden documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/hidden).

Comment: This is deprecated in newer versions of Material UI

Answer (score 7):

In **MUI v5**, you can change the [`display`](https://mui.com/system/display) value directly on `Grid` without having to use `Box` anymore:

```
<Grid
  item
  xs={3}
  sx={{
    display: { xs: "none", lg: "block" }
  }}
>
  <span>YY</span>
</Grid>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

Already been answered but can be done another way, instead of 'display', you can also use your boolean State value.

```
const [isDisplay, setIsDisplay] = useState<boolean>(false);

return (
 <>
  {
   isDisplay && <YourComponent/>
  }
 </>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Grid Items just setup your layout.

They don't actually display anything.  The MUI display option is for hiding specific elements.

Try this:

```
function CRUDView() {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={1}
      direction="row"
      justify="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
        <span>XX</span>
      </Grid>
      //removed from the below Grid Item
      <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
        <span display={{ xs: "none", lg: "block" }}>YY</span>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

That will hide the individual `span` element even though the grid is still there.

Comment: When I delete  `xs={6}` the Grid disappears but what is inside does not, so I still can see `YY` text

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, I edited my answer to reflect what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunatelly it doesn´t work either.