# Using Material-UI System with Default Components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to use [Material-UI System](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/) with the default Material UI components?  For example, this currently does **not** work:

```
<AppBar bgColor="secondary.main"  p={{ xs: 2, sm: 3, md: 4 }}>...</AppBar>
```

I am wondering, though, is there a way to get this to work (not just for `AppBar`, but for any Material UI component)?  I.e., is there a way to integrate System with the default Material UI components?

If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Box component](https://material-ui.com/components/box/#box) can be used to add the Material-UI System features to other components by using its `component` prop. One caveat is that if you try to change styling that is explicitly controlled by the component, you may run into specificity issues. For instance the styling of the background color on the `Button` in my example below doesn't work correctly if you flip the order of the `Button` and `Box` imports since this causes the order of their styles in the `<head>` to also be flipped.

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { ThemeProvider as SCThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { useTheme, StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiAppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar)`
  background-color: red;
  ${props => props.theme.breakpoints.up("sm")} {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  ${props => props.theme.breakpoints.up("md")} {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
  }
  ${props => props.theme.breakpoints.up("lg")} {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
  }
`;
export default function App() {
  const muiTheme = useTheme();
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <SCThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        <Box component={AppBar} p={{ xs: 2, sm: 3, md: 4, lg: 5 }}>
          Sample AppBar 1
        </Box>
        <div style={{ height: "100px" }} />
        <Box component={Button} bgcolor="secondary.main">
          Sample Button
        </Box>
      </SCThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit MUI theme breakpoints with styled-components]

Related answer: [Material-UI Grid does not hide whe use Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189940/material-ui-grid-does-not-hide-whe-use-display/58192229#58192229)

Comment: Thanks -- much appreciated.